# Select records (MySQL) with JOIN avoiding duplicates from the first table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to extract data from my MySQL DB data from two tables

I am able to get the data but I realized that I received more data that I actually need

I would like to optimize the query.

Here are the two tables

```
Table countries:
   id
   flag
   latitude
   longitude
   zoom

Table countries_translation:
   id
   id_country
   name
   language_code
   isDefault
```

The query that I have been using is this

```
SELECT 
   countries.id, countries.flag, countries.latitude, countries.longitude, countries_translation.name
FROM 
    countries
JOIN 
    countries_translation
ON
    countries.id=countries_translation.id_country
```

The result of this query is:

```
15, italy.png, 12.7503486, 120.835363138175, Italy
15, italy.png, 12.7503486, 120.835363138175, Italia
15, italy.png, 12.7503486, 120.835363138175, Italia
```

The above result is correct but I would like to have the common data (id country, flag, latitude, longitude) retrieve only once.

This is what I would like to achieve

```
15, italy.png, 12.7503486, 120.835363138175, Italy
                                             Italia
                                             Italia
```

The idea is to loop through those records and print the common data plus the different translations available.

Which is the most performing solution to achieve my result?

Thanks everybody

Comment: use `distinct`.....

Comment: @maSTAShuFu The `DISTINCT` does not work